# How to display a site in a browser [ubuntu/rider]

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, rider

I want to learn how to display an ASP.NET site that was compiled into a JetBrains Rider environment in a browser. P.S. The site was compiled and displayed build success.

/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe --address=127.0.0.1 --port=5001
xsp4
Listening on address: 127.0.0.1
Root directory: /home/insomnia/RiderProjects/WebApplication/WebApplication
Listening on port: 5001 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.